# I can't print things into outfile

Tags: java, printwriter

I can't seem to print what I want to print to the "transaction-list.txt" file. It did however create the file, but it prints nothing into it when the program is running. It suppose to worked seamlessly, just don't know why.
Here's my code:

```
    final String acc_name= "Edward";
    final int acc_num=123456;
    final int acc_password=456789;
    boolean quit = false;
    int i;

    PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter("transaction-list.txt");
    outFile.println("HELLO!");

    //to output timestamp
    String timestamp = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss").format(new Date());
    //System.out.print(timestamp);

    //ask user to key in the account number and password and stores it into acc_num and acc_password variables
    String stringAcc_num = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your account number: ");
    int Acc_num = Integer.parseInt(stringAcc_num);

    String stringAcc_password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your account password: ");
    int Acc_password = Integer.parseInt(stringAcc_password);


    while (Acc_num != acc_num || Acc_password != acc_password){


        for (i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {

            String error = "YOUR ACCOUNT NAME AND YOUR ACCOUNT PASSWORD IS NOT A MATCH!!";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, error, "ALERT!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

            stringAcc_num = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your account number: ");
            Acc_num = Integer.parseInt(stringAcc_num);

            stringAcc_password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your account password: ");
            Acc_password = Integer.parseInt(stringAcc_password);

            if (Acc_num == acc_num && Acc_password == acc_password)
            break;

        }//end for


        if (i > 2){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "NO MORE TIRES!", "ALERT!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(0);
        }//end if


     }//end while



    if (Acc_num == acc_num && Acc_password == acc_password){

        //to read the data from port-account.txt file
        Scanner readFile = new Scanner (new FileReader("port-account.txt"));

        //to create a txt file name "transaction-list.txt" 
        //PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter("transaction-list.txt");

        int current_balance = readFile.nextInt();

        do{

            //to pop out a message box
            String stringOption = "1. Transfer an account" + "\n2. List recent transactions" + "\n3. Display account details and current balance" + "\n4. Quit" + "\nPlease enter a number base on the following options above.";

            //to convert String into Int and stores it into "option"
            int option = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, stringOption, "Menu options", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE));


            switch(option){ 
            case 1: 
                String Case1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter an amount to transfer: ");
                int amount_transfered = Integer.parseInt(Case1);

                int newCurrent_balance = current_balance - amount_transfered; //data from port-account.txt - user input amount

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, timestamp + "\nAmount transfered: $"+amount_transfered + "\nCurrent Balance: $"+newCurrent_balance, "Amount transfer complete!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                //print it to transaction-list.txt file
                outFile.println("Current Balance: $" + newCurrent_balance);
            break; 

            case 2: 
                System.out.print("testing123! testing123!");
            break; 

            case 3: 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\nAccount Name: "+acc_name + "\nAccount Number: "+acc_num + "\nCurrent Balance: $"+current_balance, "Account Details", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            break; 

            case 4: 
                System.exit(0);
            break; 


            default:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The number you have input is invalid. Please try again.", "ERROR", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }//end switch 

        }/*end do*/ while (!quit); //repeat do loop while "!quit"(not quit).

        outFile.close();
        readFile.close();

    }//end if

}
}
```

Comment: This is quite a long code. Where exactly are you doing the printing? Are you flushing the outputstream?

Comment: I can't seem to print what I want to print into the "transaction-list.txt" file. And I don't know why, it suppose to worked.

Comment: Which line in your code is supposed to print into the file?

Comment: Instead of system.exit in option 4 just exit the loop. I guess that will do the job.

Comment: outFile.println("HELLO!"); and 
outFile.println("Current Balance: $" + newCurrent_balance).....It print nothing to the transaction-list.txt file

Answer (score 1):

**Call `flush()` on your `outFile`.**

While the javadoc for `Writer` tells us that `close()` calls `flush()` first, the code in `BufferedWriter#close()` (which the underlying `Writer` of `PrintWriter`) doesn't actually flush the buffer (as opposed to  `BufferedWriter#flush()`).

So in essence you only write to a buffer, which doesn't necessarily invoke writing to the actual OS output stream, which doesn't get flushed on writer closure.

**Get rid of `System.exit()` call.**

You should also note that if you exit via a `System.exit()` call (generally a bad practice) at one of your switch branches, even `close()` is not called.

**NB**

You could easily have solved this yourself if you created a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) first (which would in essence be a unit test for your file writing code). You also would not be downvoted for a long excerpt of code which is largely irrelevant to the problem you're experiencing.

Comment: Pardon me, I am still new to Java, I have still not yet learn about the BufferedWriter you just mentioned.

Comment: And close() won't be called at all when shortcut to exiting via System.exit() ...